# What does request.user refer to in Django?

Tags: python, django, email, django-templates, django-views

I have confusion regarding what does **request.user** refers to in Django?
Does it refer to **username** field in the **auth_user** table or does it refer to User model instance?

I had this doubt because I was not able to access email field in the template using `{{request.user.username}}` or `{{user.username}}`.

So instead I did following in views file:

```
userr = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
```

And passed `userr` to the template and accessed email field as `{{ userr.email }}`.

Although its working but I wanted to have some clarity about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your template is receiving [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser), the reference to `{{request.user.email}}` will not be found. Previously, you must ask if `{{request.user.is_authenticated }}`.

You must check if it is included `django.core.context_processors.auth` context processor in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` section of settings. If you are using Django 1.4 or latest, then context processor is `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`. This context processor is responsible to include user object in every request.

Comment: Is request.user passed by default to the template or to be done explicitly? And in some places i have seen use of {{user.is_authenticated}}. Does that work as well?

Comment: Thanks @Emigue. U mean to say that django.core.context_processors.auth is for versions less than 1.4 ? And {{user.is_authenticated}} works as well ?

Answer (score 18):

`request.user` is User model object.

You cannot access request object in template if you do not pass `request` explicitly.
If you want access user object from template, you should pass it to template or use RequestContext.

Comment: And how to get the current user? Is my way of accessing it in views, the right way?

Comment: `request.user` is current logged-in user if user logged in. Else it's AnonymousUser.

Comment: @SumeetDhariwal, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user

Comment: So if i want to update the email field in views, can i do it like request.user.email = "abc@in.com"   and then request.user.save()... ?

Comment: @SumeetDhariwal, Make sure user is logged in by `user.is_authenticated()`. AnonymousUser has no email field.

Comment: Thanks @falsetru for the explanation. One more doubt that why my way of accessing it in the view working ? I mean does request.username by default prints username field. Like we use unicode funtion in our custom models ?

Comment: [Request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) object does not have `username` attribute. It should raise error if access by `request.username`. Did you assigned `username` to `request`?

Comment: oops a little typo... i meant request.user

Comment: [Request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) have a [user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) attribute.

Comment: @falsetru as you said if the user is logged in then ```request.user``` will refer to the logged in user but my doubt is if the user is anonymous then ```request.user``` will refer to what??

Comment: @PrateekGupta, [I commented about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312831/what-does-request-user-refer-to-in-django/17312937?noredirect=1#comment25109836_17312937).=> [`AnonymousUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object)

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon what you set .

So, it is better to use

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
```

Actually, you don't need to define such variables if you append `'django.core.context_processors.request'` into the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` list in `settings.py`

Then you can access the variable {{ request.user.username }} in templates if you are using `render` in `views.py`

Comment: Thanks @Suhail for correcting me out there.  I think my code was probably working because User model by default prints username field. Like the way we define __unicode__ function in our custom class ? Is it so??

Answer (score 1):

request.user refers to the actual user model instance.

request.user.FIELDNAME will allow you to access all the fields of the user model

Comment: But request has to be passed. Is it ??

Comment: request is passed to django template like this.
`render(request, 'templatename', {'a' : 'b'....})`
The 3rd a parameter is context dictionary