# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am currently working on a project that would take in a users information and store it. My problem is I keep running into this NOT NULL constraint failed with the user id error. I believe this comes from having a null user when the form is trying to save, but don't know what I could do to fix it. I tried using this line:

```
form.user = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

but it didn't work and gave me this error:

> NameError at /users/pii/
>
> name 'self' is not defined

Any help or advice that would point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = GENS, default = '')
    birthday = models.DateField(default = '1900-01-01')
    address = AddressField(on_delete=False, blank=True, null=True)
    race = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = RACES, default = 'x')
    ethnicity = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = ETHNICITIES, default = 'x')
    income = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = INCBRACKET, default = 'x')
    education = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = EDUCATION, default = 'x')
    employment = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = EMPLOYMENT, default = 'x')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
    def save(self, *args, **kawrgs):
        super().save(*args, **kawrgs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

**views.py**

```
def PII(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PIIForm(request.POST,)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('finalpii')
    else:
        form = PIIForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'users/pii.html', {'form':form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class PIIForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birthday = forms.DateField()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
        'gender',
        'birthday',
        'address',
        'race',
        'ethnicity'
        ]
```

Comment: You don't need `self` - the `request` is the argument of the view. No need in querying `Profile.objects.get(` as well - `request.user` is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312831/what-does-request-user-refer-to-in-django

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add data to ModelForm object before saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126983/add-data-to-modelform-object-before-saving)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to edit your `user` field of `Profile` model as...

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

`null=True`, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database. Default is False.

`blank=True`, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. Default is False.

Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` commands and then you can add a profile with `Null` user.